# Volume-mesh of a closed Region?

Tags: finite-element-method, regions, mesh

For an examplary given surface mesh (example from documentation `DiscretizeRegion` )

```
sf=DiscretizeRegion[ParametricRegion[{Cos[u]/2, 3 Cos[v]/2 + Sin[u]/2, Sin[v]}, {{u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, 0, 2 \[Pi]}}]]
```

[image]

I would like to mesh the enclosed volume.

I know `BoundaryMeshRegion` evaluates the surface of a given volume, but couldn't find a "InverseFunction" which meshes the volume enclosed by a closed surface mesh!

Thanks

Comment: Assuming `sf` is a watertight and self-intersection free mesh, this should work: `BoundaryMeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[sf], MeshCells[sf, 2]]`.

Comment: @GregHurst Thanks, but   `BoundaryMeshRegion` create  a surface mesh again, or am I wrong?

Comment: @GregHurst Thanks again, now I got it!

Comment: It seems that there are two singular bands in this surfaces make the boundary discretize work fail.

Comment: @cvgmt Thanks, I tried `MeshRepair[]` but didn't succeed

Comment: Your sf region has problems. ![FindMeshDefects[sf]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VocH5.png) The colored areas are where the problems are. I will try to another example.

Answer (score 2):

There are issues when converting that parametric object to a mesh. FindMeshDefects finds multiple defect.

Therefore, I created a different parametric object, two interlocked tori. If I needed your specific object, then I believe, with more effort, that I could created the original object correctly.

The illustrations are low-order. I was successful generating objects with more than 100,000 tetrahedrons.

```mma
steps = 4
unit = (2*Pi)/steps
p = ({0, Cos[#1], Sin[#1]} & ) /@ (unit*Range[0, steps]); 
t1 = TranslationTransform[{0, -3, 0}]
p1 = t1[p]; 
p2 = (RotationTransform[#1, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}][p1] & ) /@ 
    (unit*Range[0, steps]); 
Dimensions[p2]
Graphics3D[{Point[Flatten[p2, 1]]}, Boxed -> True, 
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> 
   (Style[#1, Bold, Red, Large] & ) /@ {"X", "Y", "Z"}]
faces = Rationalize[
    N[Flatten[Table[{Triangle[{p2[[i,j]], p2[[i,j + 1]], 
          p2[[i + 1,j + 1]]}], Triangle[{p2[[i,j]], 
          p2[[i + 1,j + 1]], p2[[i + 1,j]]}]}, {i, steps}, 
       {j, steps}], 2]]]; 
coordinates = Sort[Union[Flatten[(#1[[1]] & ) /@ faces, 1]]]; 
sf1 = BoundaryMeshRegion[coordinates, 
   {Triangle[Table[Flatten[(Position[coordinates, #1] & ) /@ 
        triangle[[1]]], {triangle, faces}]]}, Boxed -> True, 
   Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> 
    (Style[#1, Bold, Red, Large] & ) /@ {"X", "Y", "Z"}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]
FindMeshDefects[sf1]
sf2 = (TranslationTransform[{0, 3, 0}] @* 
    RotationTransform[Pi/2, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}])[sf1]
sf = RegionUnion[sf1, sf2]
Head[sf]
Get["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[sf, "NodeReordering" -> True, 
   MeshOrder -> 2]
mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "MeshElements"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

At steps = 30, object looks quite reasonable. Unfortunately, at steps = 36, Mathematica breaks.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

By the way, BoundaryMeshRegion is defined by its faces and is filled (defines its volume). MeshRegion is defined by its objects and is not filled (defines its area).

Of course, I may have missed something.